# Is there any way to match a string set in C++?

Tags: c++

*EDIT:*

I know this would be easy if it were an `enum`, but I can't use an `enum` for this particular occasion. I actually need a string for further processing.

---

For example, I have four state strings:

```
IDLE, STARTED, STOPPED, PAUSED
```

and a function which imbibes a one of these states:

```
setState(const std::string &state);
```

is there a quick way to verify that the input state is one of the four strings without using a giant `if` statement like this:

```
if (state == "IDLE" || state == "STARTED" || state == "STOPPED" || state == "PAUSED") { 
// use code
}
```

Comment: Why isn't this an enum?

Comment: @chis already said it but I'll say it again, it's ridiculous that this is not an enum

Comment: Because I need to use the string for something else and I don't want to use a lexical cast.

Comment: Try `std::map` or `std::hash_set`.

Comment: @chris: An enum would certainly seem better than a string, but I've not figured any nice way to make a C++ enum which can support things like Boolean operators, other than by explicitly defining the operators for every type that needs them.  Is there any nicer way?

Comment: For a small number of strings, the "giant if" is the most straight-forward way, and probably pretty fast too. Wrap it in a function and it will be painless.

Comment: @TylerJandreau would you consider an enum class `myEnum` together with a `map<myEnum,string>`?

Comment: P.S. What does the question have to do with a truth table?

Comment: @supercat, Honestly, I've used a macro to create a more enhanced enum type out of them before (for flags one at least).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to always use an enum. But if you must stick with std::string, then I would recommend something like this:

```
#include <unordered_set>

static void setState(const std::string &state)
{
    static std::unordered_set<std::string> states {{ "IDLE", "STARTED", "STOPPED", "PAUSED" }};
    if (states.find(state) == states.end())
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid state");

    // Continue...
}
```

Comment: A good idea if you have a *large* set of allowed states, but I doubt it would be helpful for just a bunch of values. +1 anyways, it's a valid suggestion.

Comment: I'd put it in a seperate `is_state_valid` function, so it can be used uniformly everywhere

Comment: @MooingDuck agreed, +1. I just won't change the code to keep the answer simple.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
std::string tmp[] = {"IDLE", "STARTED", "STOPPED", "PAUSED"};
std::set<std::string> allowedStates(tmp, tmp + sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp[0]));
```

(maybe in a static variable or something)

and then:

```
if (allowedStates.find(state) == allowedStates.end())
{
  //state is invalid
}
```

Comment: @DiegaGiagio's way of initializing the `set` is much more readable imho.

Comment: @us2012 That way also doesn't work if you aren't up to a C++11 compiler though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "quick way". If this is about efficiency, I'd first switch on the size:

```
bool verify_state( const std::string& state ) {
  switch( state.size() )
  {
  case 4: return state=="IDLE";
  case 6: return state=="PAUSED";
  case 7: return state=="STARTED" || state == "STOPPED";
  default: return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a good standard lib imeplementation *already* do the size check for you if appropriate for the hardware?

Comment: Whether it's more readable than the 'giant' `if` block is questionable though :)

Comment: @us2012, that's why you put it in it's own function, so you don't have to read it - you just give it a self-descriptive name.

Answer (score 1):

BartoszKP's solution with an STL set is probably the best simple solution.

If you are really keen, you can simulate a poor-man's hash with something like this:

```
const unsigned nIdle('ELDI');    // "IDLE" with byte order reversed
const unsigned nStarted('RATS'); // "STAR" with byte order reversed
const unsigned nStopped('POTS'); // "STOP" with byte order reversed
const unsigned nPaused('SUAP');  // "PAUS" with byte order reversed

bool Verify(const char *szState)
{
    unsigned nState = *reinterpret_cast<const unsigned *>(szState);

    switch (nState)
    {
        case nIdle:
        case nStarted:
        case nStopped:
        case nPaused:
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::string s[] = {"IDLE", "STARTED", "STOPPED", "PAUSED", "INVALID"};
    for (auto itr=std::begin(s); itr!=std::end(s); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << *itr << '\t';
        if (Verify(itr->c_str()))
            std::cout << "OK";
        else
            std::cout << "Fail";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You need to be sure of your data.  Any string shorter than sizeof(unsigned) might be risky and you need to be sure that the string is unique with its first 4 bytes.  e.g. "STOPPED" and "STOPPING" are identical for 4 bytes.

You could do a proper hash, but that may not be faster than comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Don't use strings, use an enum to represent the internal state of the state machine and convert to string when needed:

```
namespace State
{
    enum Type
    {
        IDLE, STARTED, STOPPED, PAUSED
    };

    std::string names[] = { "IDLE", "STARTED", "STOPPED", "PAUSED" };
}
```

Then the compiler forces you to use a valid state. You then use the names array to get a string from the enum value for other processing. You can even use static assertion to make sure that the number of enums and strings matches.

Alternately `boost::enum` even provides a mechanism to create such an enumerated type with built in conversions to and from strings.

Comment: Even better an `enum class`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BartoszKP, It does. It now has static typing.

Comment: I can't use `enum` because I need the string for something else and don't want to have to lexical cast.

Comment: But the question wasn't "how to have static typing" but "is there a quick way to verify that the input state is one of the four strings"

Comment: @BartoszKP Yes, thank you. I already know about static typing.

Comment: @TylerJandreau You could have a string array/vector on the side and use the index of the enum to find the corresponding string.

Comment: @TylerJandreau you could use a regex but realistically this should be an enum and you could store the string somewhere else

Comment: I agree with @aaronman and Mark's answer. Really the OP should not be passing around a string and using that as communication data when an enum or some kind of integral type will do. Especially if you want it to be efficient, checking string equality will involve more machinery under the hood compared to just a simple integral check. As Mark's answer shows, turning that enum to a string when needed is trivial to do.